# How to kill process and make it return specific error code

Tags: linux, gdb, system-calls

How can I kill a Linux process and make any `waitpid()` calls waiting for it get a specific error code?

An example use case is when I want to pretend a long-running test has successfully finished without having to wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked and answered by Brendan Dolan-Gavitt on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/moyix/status/1484342467205816325). His solution for x86_64 is:

```
gdb -p <pid> -batch -ex 'set {short}$rip = 0x050f' -ex 'set $rax=231' -ex 'set $rdi=0' -ex 'cont'
```

(I'm posting it on Stack Overflow so I will find it a year from now when I need it.)